# How do I deploy ruby into a server without compiling or installing?

Tags: ruby, linux, deployment, installation

I'm given a server without any root access and very limited access to do any stuff. And I'm trying to install ruby on that box. I have a look at Omnibus chef and it looks like they pack embedded-ruby inside the package. So, the server doesn't need ruby installed on that box. I'm trying to achieve the same thing. How can I package my own embedded ruby so I can deploy like a tarball to the box without any compiling or installing?

Comment: Look at [RVM](http://RVM.io). It has pre-built binaries for many versions of Ruby, and can install in your home directory so you don't need admin rights. Be aware that many gems take advantage of C or system libraries and need to compile their interfaces so you will be limited to pure Ruby gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RVM](https://rvm.io) supports installing pre-built binaries (RVM installs Rubies local to the user, no admin access required):

http://syntaxi.net/2012/12/21/installing-prebuilt-binaries-with-rvm/

It's a little different than just dumping a tarball on the machine, but it will setup paths and everything for you, so odds are it will actually work.